# Cross-browser solution for CSS 'position:sticky'

Tags: javascript, css

[Position sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) is not yet been utilized in all browsers, but I saw some browsers using sticky position.

Is there a way for it to implement across older-browsers (IE 7+) ?

Comment: Polyfills? [A](https://github.com/philipwalton/polyfill/tree/master/demos/position-sticky) [few](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky) exist.